# Error arcpy copy feature management problem when making join to shapefile

Tags: arcpy, error-000210

I am trying to join a csv file to a shapefile based on an ID field that keeps giving me this error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\geo.gdb\2010reg
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\geo.gdb"
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False

# Set local variables for join  
inFeatures = r'C:\Users\shapefile1.shp'
layerName = "ID"
joinTable = r"C:\Users\csv1.csv"
joinField = "ID"
outFeature = r"C:\Users\geo.gdb\successJoined.shp"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inFeatures,  layerName)

# Join the feature layer to a table
AddJoin_management(layerName, joinField, joinTable, joinField)

# Select desired features from veg_layer#
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layerName, "NEW_SELECTION")

# Copy the layer to a new permanent feature class
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeature)
```

I would like to copy all matched rows to a new output feature class. I do not want it to contain non-matching rows. The key "ID" is the same in both the csv and the shapefile. I am getting the error above that will not allow the final copy to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within your [Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) function, you can set the join type to "Keep Common". This will only join features where ID = ID.

If you are trying to do a "Select By Attribute" function to find where ID = ID, this is not needed if you use the join type mentioned above.

The reason why the [Copy Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) tool doesn't work, is because you have set your workspace as a GDB, and then trying to export the final joined dataset as a shapefile. If you want the final output to be a shapefile, you need to set your workspace to a folder, rather than GDB.

If you want our output as a shapefile, use:

```
env.workspace = r"path/to/folder"

outFeature = r"C:\Users\geo.gdb\successJoined.shp"
```

If you want it to be a feature class, use:

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\geo.gdb"

outFeature = "successJoined"
```

Dependant on which output you want, you should input the above into:

```
import arcpy
env.workspace = 
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False

# Set local variables for join  
inFeatures = r'C:\Users\shapefile1.shp'
layerName = "ID"
joinTable = r"C:\Users\csv1.csv"
joinField = "ID"
outFeature = 

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inFeatures,  layerName)

# Join the feature layer to a table
AddJoin_management(layerName, joinField, joinTable, joinField, "KEEP_COMMON")

# Copy the layer to a new permanent feature class
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeature)
```